# How to get rid of repetitive 'Modify Setup' pop-ups when using Jupyter notebooks in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, popup

Lately, I've been running some Jupyter notebooks in VS Code, and I've been encountering a strange issue: whenever I open such a file, I am bombarded with pop-ups that look like this:

[image]

Sometimes a few will pop up; other times it can be upwards of 10 pop-ups. What's bizarre about this is that I already have my VS Code set up properly, and I can run my Jupyter notebooks just fine. I've tried selecting the 'Modify' option and going with the default selections just to make it go away, but no dice. How do I prevent these annoying pop-ups?

Comment: Can you try to ensure that your vscode is set up properly? Take a look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support

Comment: Also, perhaps you can follow these steps too @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61222320/cant-run-jupyter-notebook-in-vscode-vallia-python-windows-10

Comment: @jarrettyeo Thanks for the tips! But that's what's interesting (and I should have specified this): I can already use and run Jupyter notebooks just fine. Yet these pop-ups occur regardless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your new comments, can you [check your default settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36789145/5305519) to see which application is targeted to open .ipynb files? Perhaps .ipynb files are linked to open (strangely) via the Setup exe.

Comment: Which setting should I be looking at for this? And where exactly do I find it? I looked through File>Preferences>Settings>File but didn't see anything that resembled what you were talking about.

Comment: Check this out https://dev.to/thegeoffstevens/vs-code-settings-you-should-customize-5e75

Comment: Alright, I figured out how to do what you mentioned. There was a pretty obvious explanation in the previous link you sent me too, but I somehow missed it. My bad! When I opened my settings.json, it didn't really specify anything for what application opened ipynb files. It just recognizes them as notebooks ("viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb") and specifies the python path as "c:\\Users\\Owner\\Downloads\\python-3.9.5-amd64.exe". Do I need to change either of these?

Comment: Oh that is the problem, your python path links to your Python installer, not your actual Python executable. Use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/647798/5305519 to find your path, then update it

Comment: It worked!! Two things I'll note on the way out:

First, I was not able to use the method you showed me to find the path; I had to manually search for Python in Windows 10 as the commands suggested on that question did not work for me. I'll try to get to the bottom of that sometime.

Second, for anyone looking at this in the future, you might get an error when updating your python path in the VS code JSON. It's an easy fix: use double backslashes instead of single backslashes, so that the code knows how to handle the original backslashes!

Thanks again :)